# Dobro guitars strings and tuning

Tags: guitar, alternative-tunings, resophonic

Having just made a foray into Dobro guitars, finding one that needed some refurbishment, I assumed that the tuning was standard EADGBE, as a normal guitar. Doing some research, I find it's not. For Bluegrass at least, it's GBDGBD. Bit of a surprise, as this isn't a common open tuning for slide guitar. Another surprise was that it's usual to play resophonic guitars using a bar, as in slide playing. Especially as I got the action down to something nice for 'ordinary' playing!

Why did this tuning get chosen? And what gauge strings would be suitable for GBDGBD? I fear a standard set won't do the neck a lot of favours.

Comment: Watching with interest, though like many "the way it is" conventions, I doubt it was "chosen" in one pivotal moment but rather evolved, even if perhaps over a short period.

Comment: I don’t think you were supposed to change the action. The one time I played a dobro, the action was like 1/2" from the fretboard because it’s 100% slide bar instrument. Like lap steel or pedal steel. For your second question, a search for "dobro strings" would reveal many sets with gauges specifically made for resonators.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I guess you're right. It's my ignorance, never having even seen one played. Might get another bridge to raise the action again. Shows the value of doing some homework first! Tuning wise, using light-ish strings, I reckon I'll get away with a standard set, as some are tuned as in a standard guitar anyway.

Comment: I don't have the full historical background, but a couple important notes:  A dobro has a shorter scale than a standard guitar, so having appropriate tension will bring it to a different range of suitable pitches. Also, I thought "6th" tuning was more common than open major because it allows playing both major and minor chords.  Example: G6, D-G-D-G-B-E used by David Gilmour.

Comment: I've only ever played one dobro - an early 1930s Regal Resonator. It was tuned in standard E & had a properly playable action. They weren't all built for just slide. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f3yW.jpg Also, rather more famously - Mark Knopfler - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ogF2tRNZRk [idk what tuning]

Comment: I am not sure about the reason for this tuning, but a lot of bluegrass songs are in G major key. Many of them just contain G, C and D major chords. Banjo (another typical bluegrass instrument) is tuned GDGBD. The players play these two instruments by picking. So I guess the open G tuning was the best choice for bluegrass players. There are other tuning possibilities however.

Comment: @Theodore - standard guitar scale is around 25 1/2"-26". My resophonic (Dobro style) is 25", so not a difference worth putting into the equation, I feel.

Comment: @Tim I forget that most people think of "Dobro" as what you describe. I used to have a vintage lap steel (*made by Dobro Company* in Chicago) that was much shorter. (No longer have it, so can't measure.)  Some searches of eBay show vintage models in the 20.5" range.  It seems modern lap steels are in the 22.5-23" range, so a bit shorter than a standard guitar.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - now it's all playable - tuned GBDGBD, with light strings and low action, I'm pleasantly surprised it does play o.k. with a steel, so it'll stay like that until string-change time, when it might have a change of bridge and heavier strings, but seems good right now.